# Ruby roo gem: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

For XLS reading we are using 'Roo' gem, that time we are getting the error.

Rails 4

gem roo (1.13.2)

```
require 'roo'
class HelpTextMigration

def self.data_do
   Roo::Excel.new("/home/kanna/files/Article.xls").each do |line|
     puts "---------{line}----------"
   end
end
```

Error:

```
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4-cms-development/gems/roo-1.13.2/lib/roo/base.rb:427:in `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)
```

In Console

```
 2.1.2 :131 > Roo::Excel.new("/home/kanna/files/Article.xls").first_row
 => nil
```

Comment: which OS you are using for developement ?

Comment: could it be that `Article.xls` is an empty excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [code](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/v1.13.2/lib/roo/base.rb#L86) if seems that `first_row` will return `nil` if the default sheet (or the first sheet, if you did not assign a default sheet) does not have any non-empty lines.

Check your file to see if maybe it is empty, or if the first sheet is empty.